# How to join two dataframes based on start end end timestamps using spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

*I have two dataframes like below that contain each trip start and end timestamps*

*For example, consider a source dataframe where BUS1 departs from CITY1 at 2023-12-17 07:27:00. In a second dataframe, BUS1 arrives at CITY2 at 2023-12-17 08:27:00. then, BUS1 departs from CITY2 at 2023-12-17 08:27:00 and arrives at CITY1 at 2023-12-17 09:50:00...here we need to consider the arrived timestamp as the start timestamp when the next trip starts. This pattern follows for all other trips.*

```
 Source Dataframe                    Destination Dataframe
+----+-------------------+------+    +----+-------------------+-----------+
|  ID|START_TIMESTAMP    |SOURCE|    |  ID|  END_TIMESTAMP    |DESTINATION|
+----+-------------------+------+    +----+-------------------+-----------+
|BUS1|2023-12-17 07:27:00| CITY1|    |BUS1|2023-12-17 08:27:00| CITY2     |
|BUS1|2023-12-17 09:50:00| CITY1|    |BUS1|2023-12-17 11:13:00| CITY2     |
|BUS1|2023-12-17 12:23:00| CITY1|    |BUS1|2023-12-17 14:50:00| CITY2     |
|BUS1|2023-12-17 16:13:00| CITY1|    |BUS2|2023-12-17 07:09:00| CITY2     |
|BUS2|2023-12-17 06:08:00| CITY1|    |BUS2|2023-12-17 09:53:00| CITY2     |
|BUS2|2023-12-17 08:31:00| CITY1|    |BUS2|2023-12-17 13:31:00| CITY2     |
|BUS2|2023-12-17 11:13:00| CITY1|    +----+-------------------+-----------+
|BUS2|2023-12-17 14:44:00| CITY1|
+------------------------+------+
```

*Expected output like below*

```
+----+-------------------+-----------------------+------+
|  ID|START_TIMESTAMP    |      END_TIMESTAMP    |stop  |
+----+-------------------+-----------------------+------+
|BUS1|2023-12-17 07:27:00|    2023-12-17 08:27:00|CITY2 |
|BUS1|2023-12-17 08:27:00|    2023-12-17 09:50:00|CITY1 |
|BUS1|2023-12-17 09:50:00|    2023-12-17 11:13:00|CITY2 |
|BUS1|2023-12-17 11:13:00|    2023-12-17 12:23:00|CITY1 |
|BUS1|2023-12-17 12:23:00|    2023-12-17 14:50:00|CITY2 |
|BUS1|2023-12-17 14:50:00|    2023-12-17 16:13:00|CITY1 |
|BUS2|2023-12-17 06:08:00|    2023-12-17 07:09:00|CITY2 |
|BUS2|2023-12-17 07:09:00|    2023-12-17 08:31:00|CITY1 |
|BUS2|2023-12-17 08:31:00|    2023-12-17 09:53:00|CITY2 |
|BUS2|2023-12-17 09:53:00|    2023-12-17 11:13:00|CITY1 |
|BUS2|2023-12-17 11:13:00|    2023-12-17 13:31:00|CITY2 |
|BUS2|2023-12-17 13:31:00|    2023-12-17 14:44:00|CITY1 |
+----+-------------------+-----------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have two very specific dataframes, you don't need to join. You can simply union the two dataframe and then use windows with `lead` function to setup end timestamp and stop.

Given your source dataframe :

```scala
val sourceDataframe = Seq(
  ("BUS1", "2023-12-17 07:27:00", "CITY1"),
  ("BUS1", "2023-12-17 09:50:00", "CITY1"),
  ("BUS1", "2023-12-17 12:23:00", "CITY1"),
  ("BUS1", "2023-12-17 16:13:00", "CITY1"),
  ("BUS2", "2023-12-17 06:08:00", "CITY1"),
  ("BUS2", "2023-12-17 08:31:00", "CITY1"),
  ("BUS2", "2023-12-17 11:13:00", "CITY1"),
  ("BUS2", "2023-12-17 14:44:00", "CITY1")
).toDF("ID", "START_TIMESTAMP", "SOURCE")
```

And your destination dataframe:

```scala
val destinationDataframe = Seq(
  ("BUS1", "2023-12-17 08:27:00","CITY2"),
  ("BUS1", "2023-12-17 11:13:00","CITY2"),
  ("BUS1", "2023-12-17 14:50:00","CITY2"),
  ("BUS2", "2023-12-17 07:09:00","CITY2"),
  ("BUS2", "2023-12-17 09:53:00","CITY2"),
  ("BUS2", "2023-12-17 13:31:00","CITY2")
).toDF("ID", "END_TIMESTAMP", "DESTINATION")
```

You can obtain your result with the following code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lead}

val window = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("START_TIMESTAMP")

val result = sourceDataframe.union(destinationDataframe)
  .withColumn("END_TIMESTAMP", lead("START_TIMESTAMP", 1).over(window))
  .withColumn("stop", lead("SOURCE", 1).over(window))
  .drop("SOURCE")
  .filter(col("END_TIMESTAMP").isNotNull)
```

And you get the following result :

```
+----+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|ID  |START_TIMESTAMP    |END_TIMESTAMP      |stop |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|BUS1|2023-12-17 07:27:00|2023-12-17 08:27:00|CITY2|
|BUS1|2023-12-17 08:27:00|2023-12-17 09:50:00|CITY1|
|BUS1|2023-12-17 09:50:00|2023-12-17 11:13:00|CITY2|
|BUS1|2023-12-17 11:13:00|2023-12-17 12:23:00|CITY1|
|BUS1|2023-12-17 12:23:00|2023-12-17 14:50:00|CITY2|
|BUS1|2023-12-17 14:50:00|2023-12-17 16:13:00|CITY1|
|BUS2|2023-12-17 06:08:00|2023-12-17 07:09:00|CITY2|
|BUS2|2023-12-17 07:09:00|2023-12-17 08:31:00|CITY1|
|BUS2|2023-12-17 08:31:00|2023-12-17 09:53:00|CITY2|
|BUS2|2023-12-17 09:53:00|2023-12-17 11:13:00|CITY1|
|BUS2|2023-12-17 11:13:00|2023-12-17 13:31:00|CITY2|
|BUS2|2023-12-17 13:31:00|2023-12-17 14:44:00|CITY1|
+----+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```